# How to make debug work in post_tasks with tags

Tags: ansible

site.yml:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  post_tasks:
    - name: "List dir"
      tags: always
      shell: "ls -la"
      register: logs_result
    - debug:
        var: logs_result.stdout_lines
```

Running it:

```
ansible-playbook -t abc site.yml
```

Can't see the output. How to make `debug` always work regardless of the tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `tags: always` to the debug task should work.

```
    - debug:
        var: logs_result.stdout_lines
      tags: always
```

Comment: It obviously doesn't.

Comment: @Velkan But you haven't yet tried it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton , he hasn't tried it. I've tried it before creating the question. Have you tried it? Why are you upvoting an incorrect answer?

Comment: @Velkan If you did try it, you did not show it in the question. Please edit the question to show the actual playbook you used and the results of running it. And I upvoted the answer because it is correct. You did not place `tags: always` in the debug task.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I didn't show it in the question because "tags" in "debug" isn't even syntactically correct.

Comment: @Velkan Um, yes it is syntactically correct. I just tried it and it works fine.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you, now there is some code. The code you've added works. Indentation problem. Just saying "use tags: always" is pointless without showing any code.